# How do I revert to the old player on Last.fm?

Tags: last.fm

It seems the selection on Youtube is not as large as the original Last.fm content and their own player. I keep hearing songs repeated after only a short time! How do I revert back to the old Last.fm player to hear a wider selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last.fm no longer does [radio streaming via their own content](http://www.last.fm/forum/21717/_/2226535)

> Today we have announced significant changes to Last.fm subscriptions. From the 28th of April 2014, our subscription **radio streaming service will no longer be available**. This means that traditional subscriber radio will no longer work on any platform or device.

and [discontinuing](http://www.last.fm/forum/21717/_/2226535/_/20150974) their old player.

> It means we're discontinuing the old last.fm radio, streamed from our servers.

What you ask for isn't possible.

Comment: So sad... they had the best selection for my eclectic tastes!